# What type of Opamp for a simple buffer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, current-limiting, buffer

So I am using an Arduino Uno in my project to communicate (SPI slave) with a very tiny [pedometer](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA9555L.pdf) chip. The chip pins want max 20mA at 1.8V however Arduino outputs 5V (or some pins 3.3V) at max 50mA. So I was thinking of using a buffer amp followed by a voltage regulator (or maybe just a Zener diode) however I find it hard to pick an exact component. I would also like to power the rails for the Opamp from Arduino 5V and I could not figure what exactly to use. Preferably I would like the chips with multiple opamps inside as I will need to talk to a lot of data pins.

Excuse my lack of knowledge, I am a mechanical engineer and I am too embarrassed to keep asking my supervisor about these things!

Comment: Do you just need level shifting? In this case you dont need opamps. Where does the 20mA figure come from?

Comment: I am not sure if levelshifting will be applicable for this because it is not just voltage I am scaling down, I also need to limit the current in a controlled way. The 20mA comes from the datasheet for the chip and Arduino pins do not have current-limiting so they can definetely burn the pins if you are not careful.

Comment: Can you share the datasheet..?

Comment: http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA9555L.pdf
The electrical specs seem to start on pg. 13

Answer (score 1):

**Power supply:**

You don't have to limit the current to 20mA. You just need a PSU that respects these parameters:

[image]

[image]

You have to take the current for the I/Os as well. Many LDOs will be capable of supplying this with ease. I suggest not taking 5V from GPIO as you mention, for many reasons, but instead from the 5V bus on the Arduino.

**SPI:**

You can use an IC dedicated to level translation. [This](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scyb018h/scyb018h.pdf) document has extensive documentation on many products by TI. Page 12 lists SPI application specific ICs with different voltage ranges. I haven't checked extensively, but from that table it looks like [TXB0104](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0104.pdf) could be a good option.

Maxim also has [this](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3007) app note with some recommendations, but I found their products a bit harder to source.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot drive this 1.8V I2C sensor directly with an Arduino.

Common methods include dedicated tri-state push-pull Ic's for fastest speed or "open drain" FETs such as below for lower speeds depending on cable capacitance. Just replace the 3.3V with 1.8V+ and use a low logic level FET.
[image]

### The [MAX3370](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/maxim-integrated/MAX3370EXK-T/MAX3370EXK-TCT-ND/2351247) IC uses this topology and would be a good solution.

although a bit expensive ...

The Arduino MUST add 1.8V logic level shifters for this 1.8V sensor. Using a pullup Rs of the open drain can be changed to suit the speed  of data needed which must drive the cable load capacitance, C of typically 100pf/m for twisted pair or more for shielded pair.

> Thus the rise time is Rs*C=T determines the approximate transition time.

[**read > Effects of Varying I2C Pull-Up Resistors**](http://www.dsscircuits.com/index.php/articles/47-effects-of-varying-i2c-pull-up-resistors)

This driver resistance ultimately determines the current limit for logic signals. The sensor specifies on table 3.5 an output VOL of 0.5V max @3mA which implies a driver resistance of 0.5V/3mA=167 Ohms

- Shielded twisted pair gives better immunity but adds more capacitance thus reducing the max cable length and requires calculation of theneeded pullup resistance which consumes remote battery current when active.
- With cable delays of 5ps/m and reflections , we can neglect at these speeds.
- Step 1 : choose data comm speed you want, table 11 in 3.13.1 in spec.
- Step 2 : determine cable length , type for immunity and capacitance
- Step 3 : determine pullup R value and signal integrity from rise time.
- Step 4 : Choose a 1.8V bi-directional level shifter design to support your speed or a simple open drain MOSFET with Nch RdsOn specified for 1.8V logic, such as [***this***](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rohm-semiconductor/RUE003N02TL/RUE003N02TLTR-ND/1782322)  with 2.2k-4.7k pullup.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically ANY OP Amp should be acceptable for your application; however, theory and reality don't always work together.

Operational Amplifiers as a buffering circuit are limited by their rail to rail voltages. If you have +/- 15 volts powering your op amp then that's the max/minimum voltage you are limited to.

Additionally, when considering op amps you also need to be aware of their is an offset of the maximum voltage you can achieve with it (i forget the exact term) while you may set the rails to 5v the op amp may only be able to achieve 4.7 V maximum output (the op amp needs to consume some power for itself)

Finally, be aware of OpAmps that are not unity gain stable. This means for low gains (i.e., buffer circuit) the OpAmp will not distort your input signal.

Comment: It means the opamp will oscillate at unity gain unless you supply external compensation.